# DateObject's DateFormat option has inconsistent result in TimelinePlot LabelingFunction and by direct call

Tags: formatting, date-and-time

I want to strip time and time zone from dates in the `LabelingFunction` of a `TimelinePlot`.  I am using the `DateFormat` option of `DateObject` to reformat the display of the dates in the tooltip. The dates going in do not have a time zone component. However, in the tooltip they show with the local timezone.

```
TimelinePlot[{Interval[{DateObject[{2012, 1, 1}], 
    DateObject[{2013, 3, 1}]}]},
 LabelingFunction -> 
  Function[{val, pos, lbl}, 
   Column[DateObject[#, 
       DateFormat -> {"DayShort", " ", "MonthName", " ", "Year"}] & /@
      val]]]
```

[image]

It gets slightly more unusual as when I attempted to troubleshoot this I found that the `DateFormat` option is ignored when `DateObject` is called on another `DateObject` but the time zone does not show in this case.

```
DateObject[DateObject[{2012, 1, 1}], 
 DateFormat -> {"DayShort", " ", "MonthName", " ", "Year"}]

(* "Sun 1 Jan 2012" *)
```

This is a bit confusing.

1. Why is there a different result from what appears to be an identical call?
2. What is `TimelinePlot` doing to get the time zone and how can it be disabled?
3. What is happening with the direct `DateObject` call and how can it be made to use `DateFormat`?

Are these bugs or have I misunderstood how something works?

10.3 Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: For 3, try `Append[]`: `Append[DateObject[{2012, 1, 1}], DateFormat -> {"DayShort", " ", "MonthName", " ", "Year"}]`.

Comment: As for label replacement: `TimelinePlot[{Interval[{DateObject[{2012, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2013, 3, 1}]}]}] /. (DateFormat -> _) -> (DateFormat -> {"DayShort", " ", "MonthName", " ", "Year"})` (Yes, it looks... confusing.)